# Suddenly, google's API service says I'm in the wrong country

Tags: google-analytics, google-api, google-api-php-client, google-admin-sdk

I have several analytics API calls
that have been performing great up until recently. Now,
I've tried two servers, with different IP's and get the same result from my
queries. The IP and Results are below.

Both servers are in the USA, and I've even filled out the form located here https://support.google.com/websearch/contact/ip with no change.

The server IP information: https://geoiptool.com/en/?ip=69.12.70.137

I've even tried a different PHP client, same result.

The error received:

```
Array
(
 [http_code] => 403
 [error] => Array
     (
         [errors] => Array
             (
                 [0] => Array
                     (
                         [domain] => global
                         [reason] => countryBlocked
                         [message] => This service is not available from
your country
                     )
             )
         [code] => 403
         [message] => This service is not available from your country
     )
)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Contacts API responds with "countryBlock" error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26485851/google-contacts-api-responds-with-countryblock-error)

Comment: BTW this is a general google error it can happen with any of the APIs so even though that question relates to contacts API its valid for them all.

Comment: I've contacted google support via google apps for our company, they sent me here :/ I've also requested that the IP be rechecked, but it still returns the same errore.

Comment: @DaImTo not a duplicate. Any idea how I can get actual google assitance with this?

Comment: I doubt you will find Google assistance here. You need to apply for them to check the ip and wait for ages or move it to a different subnet.

Comment: I was told they will reply here. As a note to anyone else passing by, the script works locally just fine.

Answer (score 0):

This should be fixed for your IP, 69.12.70.137. Sorry about the trouble!