# Google AnalyticsAPI - This service is not available from your country

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I have successfully integrated Google AnalyticsAPI few days ago.
Since monday I am receiving an 403 error, which returns "This service is not available from your country".

Production-Server details : Ditigal Ocean - Amsterdam - AMS3.

The strange thing is that my Google AnalyticsAPI integration still works properly in my test-server that have the same configuration of the production-server (Ditigal Ocean - Amsterdam - AMS3).

How can i solve it?

Thanks

Comment: Which request is it exactly that is failing?  Auth? or a request to the api?

Comment: Hi @DaImTo

I'm note sure on where is exactly the problem.

This is the error:
"
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Google_Service_Exception' with message 'Error calling POST https://www.googleapis.com/upload/analytics/v3/management/accounts/103832981/webproperties/UA-4025680-40/customDataSources/scMX-QIESDyem8YlBXamlA/uploads?uploadType=media: (403) This service is not available from your country' in /var/www/script/class/Google/Http/REST.php:110"

          maybe it could be helpfull for understard better the problem.

Comment: I will forward this to the team see if they respond

Comment: Hi @DaImTo. Thanks for your reply. Can you let me know as soon as you will have some reply from the team?

Comment: llya is the team :)  From what I understand its still beta its not open in all countries.   And your Amsterdam server is one of the places its blocked.

Comment: @DaImTo thanks for your replay at first :)  ok i thought the same but i can't understand why the same code works in dev-server (dev-server is at Amsterdam too). If Amsterdam is blocked, the code con my dev-server shouldn't works too... am i right?

Comment: One would think so, however this isn't the first time I have heard of one server being blocked and another not its probably a subnet issue.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like an error, similar to the one described here
[Google Contacts API responds with "countryBlock" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26485851/google-contacts-api-responds-with-countryblock-error)

A good place to start would be filling out the Developers Console feedback form that can be found next to "Help" button in the console toolbar.

Comment: Hi Ilya. I can't find the  Developers Console Feedback Form. Can you help me?

Comment: In the top right corner of your console (https://console.developers.google.com)  you will see a question mark ("Help"), next to your Google profile icon. Click on it, and the very last item on the menu is a link to the "Send feedback" form.