# Intermittent 403 "This service is not available from your country" Error for execution API

Tags: python, google-apps-script, google-api

> https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/script/v1/rest returned
>   "This service is not available from your country">

This is an error from the google python oauth2client library resulting from the call:

```
service = discovery.build('script', 'v1', http=http)
```

Ive been working on this code on this server for 5 days. 
Until today, everything worked perfectly.

Comment: I have discovered it is possible to file bug reports / issue for google apps script google-apps-script at https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues I hope they support the execution api. Im not willing to change my ip address for such a bug / problem / issue.

its using google own library

Comment: Have you tried reading this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26485851/google-contacts-api-responds-with-countryblock-error

Comment: So ive now submitted issues:

Stackoverflow (official support site for google Apps Script ??!??): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36923117/intermittent-403-this-service-is-not-available-from-your-country-error-for-exe
Google Code Group for Google Apps Script: https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=5987&thanks=5987&ts=1461913728
And at google search IP problem checker: https://support.google.com/websearch/contact/ip

Hopefully someone will get back to me soon

Comment: Still no response from all three support channels.
Since ths code worked perfectly until it stopped working, my project is just treading water doing front end widgets until we can continue testing

Comment: There is still absolutely no response from google. 5 days I have been waiting. Submittied requests through 3 separate "support" channels.

This issue is that my DUTCH server was banned from making requests after I had been working on it for a week perfectly well. Banned for being in a restricted country.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely reason for this is you are connecting to google's api system with an http request not https. check your loGs for such. Before Python2.7.9 this was quite easy to do. I dont know about other languages

Using an http layer the google servers will allow connections for about a week, and then they shut the door.